# Linker file unselected

Tags: linker, pic, bootloader, mplab, pic32

I am dealing with a problem in my application with the linker file. What's happening is in the explorer tab it seems the linker file it's not "selected"

I have to refer that I also have a bootloader.

I'm getting an error of "(944) data conflict at address 1FC02FF8h" and I think it's related with that. Can anyone help me on that? Many Thanks.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186049/linker-file-problem?noredirect=1#comment382986_186049

Comment: Do not cross-post the same question on multiple SE sites. If a question would be more suitable for a different site, it can be migrated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Right click your linker files folder and make sure that the file is not excluded in your current config.
Edit: Right Click "Linker Files"->Properties